# Restrict multi user edit in single form using dot net core and signalr

Tags: .net-core, signalr

I have a requirement to restrict multi user edit in single form (single form - update from 2 screens - 1 update from 1 user and same update from another user should be notified in realtime).
using Dotnet core and signalR.

I gone through related to this requirement but i can't figure out this is do able or not.So some one can help on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Technologies: DataBase - Sqlserver FrontEnd - Dotnet core web application

Step1 : Need to create dotnet core web application

Step2 : Next install the signalR package

Right click the Project next choose the Add -> Client side Library option

[image: Add SignalR Package]

Step3 : Next need to add below lines in startup.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddSignalR();
app.MapHub<EmployeeHub>("/EmployeeHub");
```

Step4 : Create the Hub class for communication between the client and server without manual Request.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using SignalRCoreEdit.repository;
namespace SignalRCoreEdit.Hubs
{
  public class EmployeeHub : Hub
  {
  }
}
```

Step5 : Next need to add the script files for reference in html page

```html
<script src="~/lib/microsoft/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/clientnotification.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/signalr/dist/browser/signalr.js"></script>
```

Step6 : Next need to add the textchange event

```html
<input asp-for="viewEmployee.firstName" class="form-control" 
id="txtEmployeeName" onchange="onchangeevent();" />
```

Step7 : `Onchange()` Event in edit page

```html
<script>
    $(function onchangeevent() {
        var vId = document.getElementById("txtEmployeeid").value;
        var VCurrentId = "23";
        var vUserName = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
        var vDbEmployeeName = document.getElementById("txtDbEmployeeName").value;
        $("#txtEmployeeName").change(function () {
            var vEmpName = document.getElementById("txtEmployeeName").value;
            //alert(vEmpName);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    id: vId, Name: vEmpName, CurrentId: VCurrentId, UserName: vUserName, DbEmployeeName: vDbEmployeeName
                },
                url: "/Home/Edita",
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert('Success message');
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    //alert('Failed message');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Step8 : Add the below action in controller

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Edita(int id, string Name, string CurrentId, string UserName, string DbEmployeeName)
{
    if (DbEmployeeName != Name)
    {
        string LoginUserName = HttpContext.Session.GetString("LoginUserName");
        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMsg", Name, "Kumar", id.ToString(), LoginUserName, UserName);
    }
    return View();
}
```

Step9 : Next need to add the new js file like `ClientNotification.js`

```js
"use strict";
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/EmployeeHub").build();
connection.start();

connection.on("ReceiveMsg", function (msg, msg1, id, LoginUserName, UserName) {
    const now = new Date();
    const currentDateTime = now.toLocaleString();
    var vtxtEmployeeid = document.getElementById("txtEmployeeid").value;
    var vtxtUserName = document.getElementById("txtUserName").value;
    if (vtxtEmployeeid == id) {
        if (LoginUserName != vtxtUserName) {
            document.getElementById("eventEmployeeName").innerHTML = msg + '(' + LoginUserName + ' - ' + currentDateTime + ')';
            toastr.success("First Name Edited by " + LoginUserName);
        }
    }
})
```